# Handle WCF exceptions from webservice proxy

Tags: web-services, wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF service (.NET 4) hosted in IIS. My service contract has one method with:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(string))]
```

My service implementation for that method validates input parameters and may throw an exception like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(siteName)) { throw new FaultException("siteName is required."); }
```

The consumer program of this service is a .NET 2 console application. In this app I generated the webservice proxy by right clicking "References" and "Add web reference".

When I try to call the service method from the client app, by sending an invalid siteName, I get back a **503 Service Unavailable** exception, instead of a FaultException with the custom error message.

How can I make the FaultException, with the custom error message, propagate to the client program?

**UPDATE:**

The exception I get in the client application is this:

> System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException:
>   The HTTP service located at
>   http://www.example.com/services/myservice.svc
>   is too busy.  ---> System.Net.Web
>   Exception: The remote server returned
>   an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
>   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpCha
>   nnelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---

Comment: Well, if your clients are on .NET 2.0 and you do "Add Web reference", you're basically getting an "old-style" webservice which doesn't know anything about `FaultException` and other WCF concepts. In order to catch and handle WCF fault exceptions, you need to have WCF on the client --> .NET 3.0 or higher

Comment: Tried that by creating a new console app in .NET 4, using "Add service reference", but got the same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by a custom HTTP module in our web project. So it was not exactly a WCF problem, but a problem specific to our solution. Thanks!